# Keeping a background service alive on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service

In reference to [Accelerometer seems to only work for a few seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157178/accelerometer-seems-to-only-work-for-a-few-seconds)

I'm using the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast event to call the following:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, ShakeEventService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

Which in turn calls this:

```
public class ShakeEventService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sManager.registerListener(thisSensorEventListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

There are lots of other functions and whatnot within that class, obviously, and technically everything works fine, except that regardless of what flag I return (START_STICKY, START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY, START_NOT_STICKY, or START_REDELIVER_INTENT), the service is being killed after anywhere between 5 and 25 minutes and doesn't re-initiate until the next boot.

I've read a lot about Android 4.2 introducing new battery optimisations that kill off background processes, and I've read all sorts of bug reports with START_STICKY no longer working, but the various work-arounds seem to not be making any difference in my case. Not sure whether I'm attempting to implement them wrongly or if these workarounds have just stopped working in the more recent versions. My test device is running 5.1.1.

I'm at a bit of a loss here and would appreciate some help again please.

EDIT
For anybody else stumbling into this problem, the accepted answer below includes a working wakelock that keeps the service alive on Nexus 7 running Android 5.1.1 and LG G4 running Android 6.

Additionally, prefixing the android:process attribute of the manifest file with a colon does seem important for keeping the wakelock in place. Ref http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Still no luck on a Samsung S6 Edge running the same Android 5.1.1 though, so it looks like Samsung implement something within their battery optimisations that's causing a premature kill..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Partial [Wakelock](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) with the service. If your service is interactive with the user, you might consider making the service foreground.

This is a working example for a Partial Wakelock:

Use this when service is started:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock cpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    cpuWakeLock.acquire();
```

When the service is stopped, do call `cpuWakeLock.release();`

> imports android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver which
>   Android Studio is telling me doesn't exist.

You need to import the [support library](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/index.html) for that.

Comment: Thanks, the descriptions of wakelocks sound logical. I can't seem to get the examples working though... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html for example imports android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver which Android Studio is telling me doesn't exist, and the more direct approach referenced here http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#wakeful seems to cause similar complaints....?

Comment: Thanks for the example. I wasn't sure whether to add this to the broadcast receiver or to the onStartCommand of the service... Seemed logical to me for it to go in the service but I couldn't see how to reference context from there so I've added to the receiver. Does this look right to you? http://pastebin.com/8WyPXgsT It died a little after 6 minutes this time :-(

Comment: There is no need of referencing the context. You can use getApplicationContext() in the service itself. The reciever is intented for very short running tasks. Use the wakelock in onCreate() of the ShakeEventService.

Comment: getApplicationContext() seemed to work so I added this to a public void onCreate() block within the service and this time got the following console output: "WakeLock finalized while still held". Still died after 6 minutes though...

Comment: Actually, I've just fixed that by adding private PowerManager.WakeLock cpuWakeLock = null; to the global scope... Fingers crossed it stays alive this time!

Comment: The service should've stayed alive. What is the configuration of the device you're testing on?

Comment: It's a Samsung S6 Edge running Android 5.1.1. I've made no changes.

Comment: There must be some other problem then. Can you paste the full Service code in pastebin?

Comment: I realised the if() clause in the onCreate event was backwards and wouldn't ever fire, so replaced with if((cpuWakeLock == null) || cpuWakeLock.isHeld() == false) ... now the WakeLock finalized while still held message has returned!

Comment: Interestingly, I've just installed to an old Nexus 5 that's also running Android 5.1.1, and the service is still running after over 10 minutes.... If this stays alive then it looks like Samsung may be doing something that conflicts with the wakelock, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, there might be a power saving functionality installed on S6 that is preventing the service to run. You should put the if clause when you release the wakelock, since cpuWakeLock != null will never be true in onCreate.

Comment: It's been up for over an hour now on the Nexus so I'm going to assume the wakelock is working, and accept this answer. Still no luck on the S6 though. The battery saving crud is all disabled but it really wouldn't surprise me if Samsung still has something cheeky running. I'll do some further digging and probably start a new question for that... Thanks for all of the above, much appreciated indeed.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do to have a service that is constently alive is:

```
<!-- BackGroundService Service -->
    <service
        android:name="com.settings.BackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":my_process" />
```

2) onStartCommand should return:

```
 return Service.START_STICKY;
```

and that's all buddy after I Start the service from the main activity it is on for the whole day/

Comment: Hi Amir. For a moment there I thought my lack of an android:exported attribute was the issue, but unfortunately not. I added that in and rebooted - just over 3 minutes later, my service got killed...

Comment: Be sure it has nothing to do with the code you posted but with something else that probably causes it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing in the remaining code is causing a crash or anything like that.. It appears that the system is just killing the service after a while and this sounds like a common problem since Android 4.2. Here's the complete class: http://pastebin.com/TaVDKxhz

Answer (score 1):

To do the trick use JobScheduler and JobService which allow you to execute code periodically.

First create a class that extends JobService, then implement required methods and add your service code/start another service from within the JobService **onStartJob**() method.

Here's an example for executing a JobService operation periodically:

```
ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, yourJobService.class);
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); 
builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false); 
builder.setRequiresCharging(false); 
builder.setPeriodic(60000); // <<<<----  60 seconds interval

JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

You can find more info here: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html

Good luck!